# Pusher binding to events regardless of channel

Tags: pusher

I am attempting to listen to a particular event type regardless of the channel it was triggered in. My understanding of the docs (http://pusher.com/docs/client_api_guide/client_events#bind-events/lang=js) was that I can do so by calling the bind method on the pusher instance rather than on a channel instance. Here is my code:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('MYSECRETAPPKEY', {'encrypted':true}); // Replace with your app key 
var eventName = 'new-comment'; 
var callback = function(data) { 
  // add comment into page 
  console.log(data); 
};

pusher.bind(eventName, callback);
```

I then used the Event Creator tool in my account portal to generate an event. I used a random channel name, set the Event to "new-comment" and just put in some random piece of text into the Event Data. But, I am getting nothing appearing in my Console.

I am using https://d3dy5gmtp8yhk7.cloudfront.net/2.1/pusher.min.js, and performing this test in the latest Chrome.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Shaheeb R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pusher will only send events to the client if that client has subscribed to the channel. So, the first thing you need to do is subscribe the channel. Binding to the event on the client:

```
pusher.bind('event_name', function( data ) {
  // handle update
} );
```

This is also known as "global event binding".

I've tested this using this code and it does work:
http://jsbin.com/AROvEDO/1/edit

For completeness, here's the code:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('APP_KEY');
var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
pusher.bind('my_event', function(data) {
  alert(data.message);
});
```

Comment: Would you please clarify what you mean by "global event binding"?  Based on your code, does this mean that "my_event" messages sent to a channel called "totallyRandomChannel" will still be recognized and logged by your snippet?  What is the difference in doing pusher.bind() vs channel.bind()?  Thanks for your help!  SR

Comment: The event will only reach the client if it is subscribed to `totallyRandomChannel`. The callback on `pusher.bind` doesn't let you know what channel the event occurred on. with `channel.bind` it's clearer in your own code which channel the event was triggered on. I would recommend using `channel.bind`.

Comment: Interesting.  Is there any facility in Pusher to bind to a particular event type regardless of the channel in which it was generated?  A sort of global way to bind to a particular event?  thanks again!  SR

Comment: No. The client must be subscribed to the channel. You could instead use a global channel that all clients subscribe to and all global-type events are published on. Pusher supports publishing the same event to multiple channels which could facilitate this.

Comment: Understood.  Thank you very much for your help!  I must say, however, that I found the official documentation on this point misleading.  The docs state "You can bind to events regardless of the channel the event is broadcast to. The following is an example of an app that binds to a new-comment event from any channel:" and then go on to describe the snippet I had originally posted.  Based on your description, however, the docs are providing wrong information.  In any case, I am gratefully accepting your answer.  Thanks again!

Comment: I'll pass your comments on to the Pusher team. Pleased I could help.

Comment: But why Pusher.bind() function is not resolved?